# JQuery Clear Form on close

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have the below JQuery Dialog script, I'm trying to find out how to fire off a function that clears the form when I close the dialog.

```
function clearForm()
{
$(':input','#calcQuery')
.not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
.val('');
};
// form popup 
$(document).ready(function() 
{
//var dataString = $("#calcQuery").serialize();
    $("#formBox").dialog({
      bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false, 
        height: 600,
        width: 400, 
        modal: false,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        title: "Calculator",
        buttons:    {
            "Calculate": function() {

// form post
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "calc.php",
            data: $("#calcQuery").serialize(),
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(response)
                {
                $("#calcBox").html(response);
                $("#calcBox").show();   
                },
            error: function
                (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                    {
                    alert(xhr.status); 
                    alert(thrownError);
                    }



    }).responseText;

// form post 

                }
            } 
    });

$('#calcButton').click(function(){
    $('#formBox').dialog('open');
    return false;
    });

});

$("#formBox").bind('dialogclose', function(event)
{
clearForm();
});
```

Comment: form.reset() might do the trick...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work by using ...

```
function clearForm(form)
{
    $(":input", form).each(function()
    {
    var type = this.type;
    var tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase();
        if (type == 'text')
        {
        this.value = "";
        }
    });
};
```

and .....

```
// form post
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "calc.php",
            data: $("#calcQuery").serialize(),
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(response)
                {
                $("#calcBox").html(response);
                $("#calcBox").show();   
                clearForm("#calcQuery");
                },
            error: function
                (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                    {
                    alert(xhr.status); 
                    alert(thrownError);
                    }



    }).responseText;

// form post
```

... now .. how do I set the radio buttons back to the default of "GB" ?

```
&nbsp;KB <input type="radio" name="curr_unit" value="KB" />
&nbsp;MB <input type="radio" name="curr_unit" value="MB" />
&nbsp;GB <input type="radio" name="curr_unit" value="GB" checked/>
&nbsp;TB <input type="radio" name="curr_unit" value="TB" />
```

thanks

Answer (score 9):

This will reset the form:

```
$("#form").trigger( "reset" );
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the [close event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-close)

```
$("#formBox").dialog({
      bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false, 
        height: 600,
        width: 400, 
        modal: false,
        close: clearForm
});
```

Answer (score 3):

More elegant is a combination of your methods:

```
...
beforeClose: function() {
    $("#form").trigger("reset");
},
...
```

It will reset your form on save, on cancel and on title bar close button. 
Exception for select2 which have to be done manually:

```
$("#mySelect2").select2('data', null);
```

inside the same beforeClose

Answer (score 0):

```
`jQuery("#form").trigger( "reset" );`
```

place it into the success function **after** the success message has been displayed.
Then it works perfectly!
example:

```
success : function(){
jQuery('#contactsMsgs').html('<p class="success">All is well, your e&ndash;mail has been sent.</p>');
jQuery('#yourformname').trigger( 'reset' );
spinner.hide();`
}
```