# Ajax form only work one time

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress

My script is looking like this. **Yes**, it is from a plugin. **No**, I'm not comfortable with ajax.

How can I get this form to refresh and be able to take input once more after first submit?

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
        target: '#ps_output',      // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
        beforeSubmit:  showRequest,     // pre-submit callback 
        success:       showResponse,    // post-submit callback 
        url:           '<?php echo $link; ?>'         // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php     
}; 

    // bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
    jQuery('#thumbnail_upload').ajaxForm(options); 
});

function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
    //do extra stuff before submit like disable the submit button
    jQuery('#ps_output').html('Sending...');
    jQuery('#submit-ajax').attr("disabled", "disabled");
}

function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
    //do extra stuff after submit
    jQuery('#submit-ajax').attr("enabled", "enabled");
}
</script>
```

Thanks alot.

**EDIT**:

The callback function ends in `die()`. I read that was simply for being able to retrieve the output from the function. Does that end AJAX too?

Comment: can you provide fiddle or html source?

Comment: Since wp plugin is in question, please send link to it, and - i would say that solution is in php files related to form processing.

Comment: The php callback function ends in die..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable, you can set the `disabled` property to `false`.

```
jQuery('#submit-ajax').prop('disabled', false);
```

I would also change your code that disables it to;

```
jQuery('#submit-ajax').prop('disabled', true);
```

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

> The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method.

Comment: This works very well! Is it possible to clear the form without refreshing?

Comment: If the server side is doing `die()`, it won't matter because you aren't doing anything with the response anyway, provided the server is not quitting before it completes its processing

Comment: You can reset the form by using: `$('#thumbnail_upload').trigger('reset');`. See here for more methods of resetting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653556/jquery-javascript-function-to-clear-all-the-fields-of-a-form

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
jQuery('#submit-ajax').removeAttr("disabled");//to remove disabled attribue
```

instead of

```
jQuery('#submit-ajax').attr("enabled", "enabled");
```