# How to reset my Ajax.Begin form fields value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have the following Ajax.BeginForm inside my asp.net mvc razor view:-

```
    <div id="searchform">                           

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AdvanceSearchIndexByName","Home", 
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "get",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        LoadingElementId = "progress2",
        UpdateTargetId = "SearchTable2"
    }))
    {
       }
<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Clear" id="clear" />
```

and i wrote the following javaScript:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#clear").on('click', function () {
        alert('2');
        $('#searchform').clear();
});
        </script>
```

to reset the form values when clicking on the "clear" button, but currently the clear button will not have any effect.can anyone advice ?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe this is useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653556/jquery-javascript-function-to-clear-all-the-fields-of-a-form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without any JavaScript, just add a [reset type button](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.reset.html)

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AdvanceSearchIndexByName","Home", 
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "get",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        LoadingElementId = "progress2",
        UpdateTargetId = "SearchTable2"
    }))
 {
        <input type="reset" value="reset"/>

 }
```

Comment: what an answer,, this is exactly what i was searching for,, strange that i have been using Ajax.BeginForm on many projects, but never know about its reset capabilities ...

Comment: That's a HTML 4.0 capability! This has been around for a very long time. People just forget about it.