# Clearing a form after registration is successful

Tags: ajax

I have been trying to clear my registration form after successful registration so that it can return the same form empty without reloading the entire page. please am workiing with ajax and still new to it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633605/clear-form-values-after-submission-ajax

Answer (score 1):

jQuery:

```
$("#formID")[0].reset();
```

or in javasscript

```
document.getElementById("formID").reset();
```

you could reset the values of the form as long as you use it within `success()` or `complete()` callback function

Comment: @ChambahRussell: Hope it helped you :)

Comment: Good. Do accept the answer (click the check mark) so that the question does not add to the unanswered list. :)